# 360 image View On Ionic V2 App

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on Ionic V2 app. I need to develop 360 image view on Ionic V2 app.

Is it possible with Ionic v2 ?
If it is possible. How to integrate 360 image  view with Ionic V2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

360 image view is possible with Ionic V2 and V3.

You can follow [these](https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-news-feed-with-360-degree-photo-viewing-in-ionic-2/) procedure to develop 360 image view on your Ionic app.

Comment: The provided link states that it is only available for panorama photos. not for "true" 360° photos.